# My barcode app force closes whenever it runs

Tags: android, barcode

I got my app to read an app and then tell me what the code says, but now I'm trying to have it encode the string back into a barcode and display it as an image on the screen. However, it always force closes the app before it starts. Here is my code, please help:

```
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;

public class Main extends Activity {

IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);

private static final int WHITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
private static final int BLACK = 0xFF000000;
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

    Button btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
      IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      if (scanResult != null) {
          Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                    "works",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
          String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
          Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                    contents,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Bitmap bitmap = null;
          ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
          try {

                bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(contents, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, 600, 300);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (WriterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          myLayout.addView(iv);
          TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            tv.setText(contents);

            myLayout.addView(tv);
      }


    }
Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String contents, BarcodeFormat format, int img_width, int img_height) throws WriterException {
    String contentsToEncode = contents;
    if (contentsToEncode == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;

        hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
        hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");

    MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = writer.encode(contentsToEncode, format, img_width, img_height, hints);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // Unsupported format
        return null;
    }
    int width = result.getWidth();
    int height = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offset = y * width;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        return bitmap;

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

IntentResult and IntentIntegrator are both from ZXing.

Log Cat:

```
03-15 13:05:04.303: E/AndroidRuntime(4363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Comment: Can you post more of your logcat?

Comment: bez you are trying to find layout before setting setContentView for Activity. i don't why you comment layout line inside onCreate?

Comment: it then says that integrator isn't used, because the only time it is used is outside of onCreate, in onActivityResult

Comment: and same for the mylayout

Comment: @Corey : ok change your code as http://pastebin.com/iahnTX6r

Answer (score 0):

Try to move this:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
```

under:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: Then doesn't that create a problem when myLayout is used in onActivityResult?

Comment: No it should not, what error do you get for onActivityResult?

Answer (score 0):

In your toast, instead of `Main.this` you should try `getApplicationContext()`. Also recall that an `Activity` is a type of `Context`.

Comment: thats not the issue because that worked before I tried making the barcode an image.